# Physical intuition behind the equation of continuity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

There is a question in my book

> The cross sectional area of water falling (streamline flow) from a tap decreases as it goes down. Explain this behaviour on the basis of equation of continuity.

I know how to answer it. But finally it is just a mathematical reasoning and not phyical.

**So can someone explain me (physical reason) why the cross sectional area  of water coming down from a tap becomes lesser and lesser as it's velocity increases ?**

---

I thought of it for somedays and it is very clear to me that the water is not compressed by the surrounding pressure (since equation of continuity assumes incompressible fluid).

From above it is clear to me that in order to have lesser cross section the molecules which were in the same plane near the opening got distributed in different planes (or got stacked over one another) as they fall down and this is only possible if there is a velocity difference between each of the molecules (which were in the same plane earlier).

But I have no reason for this velocity difference except **viscosity** but this can't be true since equation of continuity assumes non viscous fluid.

**So can someone help me figuring this out ?**

**Note** : Assume the water in the above question to be perfectly ideal so as to follow equation of continuity.

Comment: -1 for being rude tp one of the users who answered you

Comment: _But I have no reason for this velocity difference_" Yes you do. The water is being accelerated which means there is a velocity difference by definition.

Comment: @joseph h I think you didn't understand my question.. gravity will change the speed of each molecule equally in equal time intervals and so the molecules which were in the same plane earlier can't get distributed in two different planes because gravity pulls all of them equally..

Answer (score 1):

An equation of continuity is typically related to some conservation law. In fact, an equation of continuity can be considered the defining feature of a local conservation law.

In the case of water flow, it is conservation of volume. That in turn is derived from the conservation of mass together with the fact that water is incompressible. The conservation of volume means that as the water stream moves faster it must get thinner.

Note that in real water flows the surface tension eventually leads to the formation of drops. Then the stream does not get thinner but rather the drops get further apart.

Comment: how does the falling molecules know that they have to become thinner in order to conserve volume ? Do they have some inbuilt sensor chips:).. you just wrote the mathematics in words .. please don't do this , I already know the mathematics behind it..

Comment: They don't "know" anything. The laws that work on microscopic levels ensure this. And the first statement about equation of continuity being related to a conservation law is sufficient and self-explanatory to answer your doubt. Please think on it further.

Answer (score 1):

Equation of continuity is all about conservation of **volumes** (as pointed out by Dale).
Consider the following diagram: 
[image: Two cylinders with same volumes but different radii]

Here, the two cylinders have different heights, but same volumes. As a result, cylinder with greater height has a lesser volume (because $V= \pi r^2 h$ is constant). 
Now consider the same situation for water falling from the tap. A constant volume of water is released from the tap. Let cross-sectional area be $A$, and height of volume of water be $x$. Thus, we know that at any point of time $V=Ax$ will be constant. Now, we can differentiate this with respect to time: $Av=constant$. 
As velocity of the flowing water increases, area has to compensate and decrease in order to maintain a constant volume. This has nothing to do with viscosity as density remains constant throughout the situation.

### Edit

Here is an intuitive description of what happens on the molecular level. Consider an opening which releases water molecules at a constant rate. 
[image] 
Now, consider a single particle of the fluid is released at $t_1$. For Case 1, let us consider a slow moving fluid with velocity $v_1$. It covers $x_1$ between $t_1$ and $t_2$.

[image] 
For Case 2, particle has a greater velocity $v_2$ and as a result it covers greater distance $x_2$ in the time interval.

[image]

In both of these cases, there is constant volumetric flow, i.e., rate of release of particles is equal. In case 1 and, the $v_1$ is slower than $v_2$ which leads to greater accumulation of particles. While there is constant addition of particles from the source, less of them "escape" per unit time in the first situation. As a result, these particles spread over a greater cross-sectional area (due to the fact that we have considered ideal flow). On the other hand, due to greater velocity in the second case, more particles escape forward per unit time and less get spread over the given cross-sectional area.

Comment: I found this description intuitive enough. Perhaps you are in search for a description on a molecular level, about the particulate behavior for the phenomena. I will update the answer later.

Comment: exactly.. waiting for your edit..;)

Comment: I have updated my answer as above. Note that I have described intuitively and some definitions may not be concrete or rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the water flowing out of the tap. There cannot be an accumulation of water at any point, so any arbitrary section of water must have the same amount of water entering, as well as leaving. From which follows the equation of continuity.

If I have a rubber hose with water flowing through, and I squeeze a particular section of it, you can see that if the water didn’t speed up at the point of compression, there would be a drop in the flow rate. This means that the water must speed up, to prevent an accumulation of water before my “squeeze point”.

Similar to the other answers but phrased differently, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The physical mechanism that narrows the stream of water is surface tension. As the water falls more quickly, its dynamic pressure drops, due to [Bernoulli’s principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle). Surface tension then narrows the stream, causing the water’s dynamic pressure to rise again until it balances surface tension.

This dynamic balance between pressure and surface tension is unstable - this is called [Rayleigh instability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%E2%80%93Rayleigh_instability) - and eventually the water stream breaks up into discrete drops

Comment: but I used Bernoulli's equation and it led me to a result that the dynamic pressure at the mouth of the tap and that at some point below it is same..

Comment: can you give the mathematics behind your claim ?

Comment: @AStudent4ever There are three independent variables in the Bernoulli equation; velocity, height and dynamic pressure. To conclude that dynamic pressure is constant you must be assuming a relationship between velocity and height. How do you justify this relationship ? Remember the water molecules in the stream are *not* moving ballistically - they are affected by the forces from the water molecules around them.